# Find source of range error in JavaScript internal file

Tags: javascript

I've recently obtained a MEAN stack project that I need to setup on my server (Ubuntu 16.04). I've compiled the code and ran the start .js file using `sudo node <file.js>` to which I receive an error:

```
throw new RangeError('"port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536');
^

RangeError: "port" argument must be >= 0 and < 65536
    at assertPort (internal/net.js:17:11)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1389:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/var/www/html/workspace/MRC/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/workspace/MRC/app.js:81:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
```

Now evidently this is a RangeError in a file looking for the port to run on. I know what needs to be fixed but I'm having one problem. The error is in "internal/net.js" which is nowhere to be found in the project. I have no idea as to if it's somehow built into JS or if its simply slipped under my radar. I know what needs to be done when I find it, but right now finding it is the hard part.

Comment: That's in node.js itself.  Look further up the stack trace.

Comment: It looks like either `application.js` or `app.js` is passing an incorrect port value to an HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `application.js` or `app.js` whether you set up your port. Try to hardcode the particular port number to locate it.